# How to understand the 'runtime' in hook_requirements?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

```
/docroot/modules/contrib/ultimate_cron/ultimate_cron.install
```

I saw some code section in the path of above. And I do not understand the meaning of the 'runtime' here. Is the answer the moment when the website running ? Or every some minite to process below code?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_requirements().
 */
function ultimate_cron_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();

  switch ($phase) {
    case 'runtime':
      $requirements['cron_jobs']['title'] = 'Ultimate Cron';
      $requirements['cron_jobs']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_OK;

      // Check if any jobs are behind.
      $jobs_behind = 0;
      $jobs = CronJob::loadMultiple();

      foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        if ($job->isBehindSchedule()) {
          $jobs_behind++;
        }
      }

      if ($jobs_behind) {
        $requirements['cron_jobs']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_WARNING;
        $requirements['cron_jobs']['value'] = \Drupal::translation()->formatPlural(
          $jobs_behind,
          '@count job is behind schedule',
          '@count jobs are behind schedule'
        );
        $requirements['cron_jobs']['description'] = [
          '#markup' => t('Some jobs are behind their schedule. Please check if <a href=":system_cron_url">Cron</a> is running properly.', [
            ':system_cron_url' => Url::fromRoute('system.cron', ['key' => \Drupal::state()->get('system.cron_key')])->toString()
          ])
        ];
      }
      else {
        $requirements['cron_jobs']['value'] = t('Cron is running properly.');
      }
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The runtime code" (case of `$phase == 'runtime'`) will be executed when you access the Status Report page (`/admin/reports/status`)
[image]

#### References:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.2.x

Comment: That is to say, the code won't be executed if i never access the Status Report page?

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.2.x). Read them for more info.

> ### function hook_requirements
>
> Check installation requirements and do status reporting.
> This hook has three closely related uses, determined by the $phase argument:
>
> - Checking installation requirements ($phase == 'install').
> - Checking update requirements ($phase == 'update').
> - Status reporting ($phase == 'runtime').
>
> The 'runtime' phase is not limited to pure installation requirements but can also be used for more general status information like maintenance tasks and security issues. The returned 'requirements' will be listed on the status report in the administration section, with indication of the severity level. Moreover, any requirement with a severity of REQUIREMENT_ERROR severity will result in a notice on the administration configuration page.

Comment: I meaning what time to excute the runtime code not the parameter explanation.

Comment: Ok, thank u very much. And do you agree with the Kien Nguyen's apinion?